# Is there away to keep a specific IP Address?

Tags: networking, ip

I need to know if it is possible to retain a specific IP address when I move my computer's geographical location?

Use case:
I have a piece of software that recognises the IP adress I have when I am at work.
For certain reasons, I cannot use the software if I am not using that specific IP address.
So when I go home, and need to change something in the software I cannot do it because my IP adress is different.

My company do not want to use a remote log in type system for various reasons, if they can avoid it.
Is there any other way to use my work IP address even when I am a home?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Ask your IT department to provide a remote login if you need access from home.

Comment: Certainly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_IP I’m not aware of any implementations though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has to do with "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks" as outlined in the site guidelines.

Comment: @DanielB, beyond the lack of widespread support, I would expect any employer who does not allow VPN access to be reluctant to configure and maintain a home agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean your public IP address, than this not possible, since your are most likely changing ISP when going from home to your job.

However you could ask for a VPN account to your compagnies IT departement (if they provide it).
In that case you could transfert all trafic via the VPN of your compagnie and appear "inside".

Comment: Even if you have the same ISP as your work, you obviously never will have the same IP address. So mentioning about changing ISP is not helping. Changing connection is. Different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know if it is possible to retain a specific IP address when
>   I move my computer's geographical location?

Do you mean temporarily or permanently? If both the source and destination ISPs are the same and you are moving premises, and you are being provided a static IP address by your ISP, it's possible they will let you take it with them.

If you mean, "can I go home each night and have the same IP address assigned to my home PC that I had at work", then no.

However, it's possible you are talking about a private IP address on your PC, rather than a public, external one (possibly one that begins 172.(16-31), 192.168 or 10.). In which case, it is trivial to change the local IP address of your home PC.